# How do I enter an array in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, graphics, data-science

Does It have a way to enter an entire array from my data set in D3.js? Or do I have to clean up It before enter?

An example of my dataset .jason is here:

```
[
{
    "promoter": "Vigun01",
    "upstream": "[2, 57, 150, 376]"
},
{
    "promoter": "Vigun01",
    "upstream": "[500, 732, 765]"
},
{
    "promoter": "Vigun01",
    "upstream": "[675]"
},
{
    "promoter": "Vigun02",
    "upstream": "[623]"
},
{
    "promoter": "Vigun03",
    "upstream": "[133, 601]"
},
{
    "promoter": "Vigun04",
    "upstream": "[599, 650]"
},
{
    "promoter": "Vigun05",
    "upstream": "[50, 789]"
}
]
```

and my script in D3.js is here:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart-area")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", "400")
    .attr("height", "400");

d3.json("data/dataset.json").then(function(data){

data.forEach(d => {
    d.upstream = +d.upstream;
});
console.log(data);

var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){
        return d.promoter;
    }))
    .range([0, 400])
    .paddingInner(0.2)
    .paddingOuter(0.2);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,1000])
    .range([0,400]);

var line = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(data);

line.enter()
    .append('line')
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('y1', (d,i)=>y(d.promoter))
        .attr('x2', 400)
        .attr('y2', (d,i)=>y(d.promoter))
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('stroke', 'black');


var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.promoter)
        })
        .attr("cx", function(d){
           return x(d.upstream)
        })
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "black";
        });


}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
});
```

I can draw single inputs, like ("Vigun01", "10"), but I can't if I have a entire array.

It's ok for me if convert ("Vigun01", "[1,2,3,4]") to many inputs like ("Vigun01", "1"), ("Vigun01", "2"), ("Vigun01", "3"), ("Vigun01", "4") but how do I do it inside my dataset?

Comment: If you want to draw multiple lines your data should be an array of arrays, where each inner array is a line. `[[...line 1], [...line 2]]`

Comment: I don't have any issue to draw the lines. My problem is for the circles, for the cx attribute to be more specific. When I loop through data set, I got a cy category and an array, but how can I draw multiple "cx" repeating all parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you need to adjust:

1. First, I suggest you change the data, such that the upstream properties contain arrays not strings. I don't see a benefit of having them as string so you should change it when you create the data.

Your code:

```
data.forEach(d => {
d.upstream = +d.upstream;
});
```

does not convert your string to an array nor to a meaningful number. It will result in NaN.

2. Since you want to draw circles for each element of your outer JSON Array on one line but vary the x position based on the upstream value array values, I suggest splitting the circle element creation in 2 steps.

First you create a `g` element for each promoter, like so:

```
var circleGroups = svg.selectAll("g.circles")
  .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "circles");
```

3. Then you create for each group element the set of circles corresponding this promoter. For that you have to slightly adjust your data and then do the data join with this.

create the new arrays for the circles of the same promoter:

```
  function getCircleData(d) {
  var cdata = d.upstream.map (function(ele) { 
    return {upstream: ele, promoter: d.promoter};
  });
  return cdata; 
  }
```

and the data join for the circles:

```
    var circle = circleGroups.selectAll("circle")
        .data(getCircleData)
    .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.promoter)
        })
        .attr("cx", function(d){
           return x(d.upstream)
        })
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "black";
        });
```

Here is the full working code. I just replaced your AJAX call with setting the array in a function.

```js
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)

// d3.json("data/dataset.json").then(function(data){
    let data = getData();

    /*
data.forEach(d => {
    d.upstream = +d.upstream;
});
console.log(data);
*/

var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){
        return d.promoter;
    }))
    .range([0, 400])
    .paddingInner(0.2)
    .paddingOuter(0.2);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,1000])
    .range([0,400]);

var line = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(data);

line.enter()
    .append('line')
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('y1', (d,i)=>y(d.promoter))
        .attr('x2', 400)
        .attr('y2', (d,i)=>y(d.promoter))
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('stroke', 'black');


    var circleGroups = svg.selectAll("g.circles")
      .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "circles");

    var circle = circleGroups.selectAll("circle")
            .data(getCircleData)
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cy", function(d){
                return y(d.promoter)
            })
            .attr("cx", function(d){
               return x(d.upstream)
            })
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "black";
            });
   
    function getCircleData(d) {
      var cdata = d.upstream.map (function(ele) { 
        return {upstream: ele, promoter: d.promoter};
      });
      return cdata; 
    }
    
    function getData() {
      var data = [
      {
          "promoter": "Vigun01",
          "upstream": [2, 57, 150, 376]
      },
      {
          "promoter": "Vigun01",
          "upstream": [500, 732, 765]
      },
      {
          "promoter": "Vigun01",
          "upstream": [675]
      },
      {
          "promoter": "Vigun02",
          "upstream": [623]
      },
      {
          "promoter": "Vigun03",
          "upstream": [133, 601]
      },
      {
          "promoter": "Vigun04",
          "upstream": [599, 650]
      },
      {
          "promoter": "Vigun05",
          "upstream": [50, 789]
      }
      ];
      return data;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```